# Sketching a set of $ 2 < |z| \leq |z + 2| < 4 $ on the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I need to sketch $ 2 < |z| \leq |z + 2| < 4 $ on the complex plane. At first, it seamed pretty easy since I know that:

- $2 < |z|$ is a circle with a center in point $0,0$ and radius = 2
- |z + 2| < 4 is a circle with a center in point $-2,0$ and radius = 4

**BUT** here comes that part $ |z| \leq |z + 2| $ and I actually have no idea how to connect those two.

Edit - my proposed solution:

$ |z| \leq |z + 2| \implies z^2 \leq z^2 + 4z + 4 \implies 0 = \leq 4z + 4 \implies -1 \leq z $

Is that correct? Is it the missing condition?

Comment: **Hint.** $|z|$ is the distance of $z$ from the origin.  $|z+2| = |z-(-2)|$ is the distance of $z$ from $-2$.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I think I have just written that. Or you mean that I can use that fact to solve my problem (I mean this part: $|z| \leq |z + 2|$)?

Comment: What points are closer to the origin than they are to $-2$?  The closed half-plane$\Re(z)\geq-1$

Comment: @theman: Yes, exactly what saulspatz said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

You cannot square both sides as if $z$ were real. Indeed, if we set $z = x + yi$, one has that
\begin{align*}
|z| \leq |z+2| & \Longleftrightarrow |z|^{2} \leq |z+2|^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z\overline{z} \leq (z+2)(\overline{z} + 2)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z\overline{z} \leq z\overline{z} + 2(z+\overline{z}) + 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 0 \leq 4x + 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\geq -1
\end{align*}

Comment: Great, that is the hint that I needed. I got right answer and I wouldn't have known that I did an error on my way. Thank you very much Sir!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to help.